# How to convert list of JSON encoded strings to list of some custom class in dart?

Tags: dart

Say I have a `Diary` class in Dart which goes something like,

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Diary {
  final DateTime createdDate;
  final String? title;
  final String body;
  final String? mood;
  // ...
  Diary.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> diaryMap)
    : createdDate = DateTime.parse(diaryMap['createdDate']),
      body = diaryMap['body'],
      title = diaryMap['title'],
      mood = diaryMap['mood'];
}
```

The code I've written so far is,

```dart
// jsonEntries is of type List<String> which are json encoded strings
final diaryEntries = jsonEntries.map((jsonEntry) => {
  Diary.fromJSON(jsonDecode(jsonEntry))
}).toList();

print(diaryEntries.runtimeType);
// Expected List<Diary>
// But getting JSArray<Set<Diary>>
```

What should I change here to get the expected result? I'm new to dart, so you answer would definitely help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I understand from you sentence that you have a `List` of `String` named `jsonEntries`, and every item of this String list is a json object.
if every item of `jsonEntries` is a json object as a String, you should fetch every item as `Diary` item, something like this:

```
var diaryList = <Diary>[];/// diaryList is the list you want

for(var jsonItem in jsonEntries){
diaryList.add(Diary.fromJSON(jsonItem));
}
```

if the result is not what you want please share the `jsonEntries` to know what is inside it.
happy coding...

Comment: Yeah your answer is almost correct except that it should do `jsonDecode` inside loop for every elements. But I'm looking for a compact one liner to do the task (like using `Iterable.map`). Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: hey, would you please send me an example of jsonEntries?